# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateCaptcha does not exist

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

I am using Laravel and I did not add any code yet but I tried integrating recaptcha into laravel's auth package. I have put the script and the recaptcha shows up at the form already. I also put validation so that the recaptcha is required. However, when I submit the form with recaptcha it throws that error. Here is my register controller from auth package:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required|captcha']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: By default Laravel does not have a `captcha` validation rule. Are you using any laravel specific package that provides such a rule or are you defining this rule somewhere?

Comment: @apokryfos most likely the OP was using: https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem,
Oddly it was working fine locally,
but in production not.

In my case, using https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha ,
I had to add:

```
Anhskohbo\NoCaptcha\NoCaptchaServiceProvider::class,
```

In the providers array in:

```
app/config/app.php
```

for it to work in production. ( step one in the README from that repo )
and since I completed step one I also completed step 2. Using Laravel 9.

I have no idea why locally, or in my other server it was working ok but not in a specific client's server..